# Passar parâmetros com properties c#

Tags: c#, propriedade, encapsulamento

Estou montando um script de lutadores, a categoria eu quero que seja um método privado e que ela seja de acordo com o peso que o usuário digitar, mas não estou conseguindo misturar esses dois atributos na função. 
categoria: string e peso: double.

O código gera erro no construtor, quando eu chamo a função set do atributo categoria.

```
class Lutador
    {
        private string _categoria;

        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public double Peso { get; set; }

        public Lutador(string nome, double peso)
        {
            Nome = nome;
            Peso = peso;
            //Erro
            Categoria = Peso;
        }

        public string Categoria
        {
            get { return _categoria; }
            set
            {
                if (Peso <= 50.0)
                {
                    _categoria = "leve";
                }else if (Peso <= 80.0)
                {
                    _categoria = "médio";
                }
                else
                {
                    _categoria = "pesado";
                }
            }

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No seu código você declara `Categoria` como tipo `string`, mas tenta inicializa-la com um `double`. Isso não apenas é um erro, mas também não faz sentido fazer dessa forma.

Se a o valor de `Categoria` será gerado a partir do `Peso`, não faria mais sentido criar um `setter` para `Peso` que também atribui valor para a `Categoria` dentro desse `setter`?

Exemplo:

```cs
class Lutador
{
    private double peso;

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    // O valor de Categoria sempre será gerado pela nossa classe, então não
    // vamos permitir que o setter seja acessado externamente
    public string Categoria { get; private set; }

    public double Peso 
    { 
        get
        { 
            return peso; 
        }
        set
        {
            // peso recebe o valor normalmente
            peso = value;
            // Categoria também recebe um valor baseado no peso
            // a seguinte expressão se chama expressão ternária
            Categoria = value <= 50.0 ? "leve" : value <= 80.0 ? "medio" : "pesado";
        }
    }

    public Lutador(string nome, double peso)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        Peso = peso;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ajudou demais, entendi bem a sua lógica, curti também a linha de raciocínio.

Comment: Outra alternativa seria criar um `get` para o `Categoria` para gerar os valores `leve`, `medio` e `pesado` apenas quando você acessar a propriedade. Acho que seria mais conciso dessa forma.